# Can php echo certain words from another file which is not php eg .scss or .css?

Tags: php, css, sass

Can php echo one words from another file which is not php eg .scss or .css?

lets say I have test.php and test1.scss

on test1.scss my text is like following:

/*  start of test1.scss content */

$theme_name : MyTheme;

/*  end of test1.scss content */

now I want to echo only MyTheme on test.php with php code. is it possible?

Comment: file_get_contents() will put the external file into a string and from there you can use regular expressions to extract the word or words.

Comment: Read the file and then process it as you need. Then echo it

Comment: Thank you for your comment, one more question
how do I echo "MyTheme" from test1.scss

Comment: Create a regular expression to look for any text between `$theme_name :`  and `;`

Comment: KevinP literally just said how.

Comment: Play with regular expressions. This: "(\$theme_name :)(.*);" selects the line with the theme name. Plus you get two groups, one containing just the "MyTheme".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file using

```
file_get_contents()
```

Then use regular expressions:

This pattern works. Group 2 contains "MyTheme"

```
$pattern = '/(\$theme_name :)(.*);/';
preg_match($pattern, $a, $results);

echo ($results[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked you guys are awesome.
:)

Comment: Welcome! You may accept the answer, if it works well.